# More text boxes in one inputbox?

Tags: vb.net, inputbox

I was wondering if there's a way to use more text boxes in a single inputbox?
So for example, I call an inputbox when a button is pressed and I want it to say something like this:

-Name: (textbox)

-Adress: (textbox)

Ok
Cancel

Where both strings can be read. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

You can create a custom form for this task. To allow a non-blocking use, you could use a callback delegate or an event that is raised whenever the user closes the form.

Answer (score 0):

As Nico said, not possible without creating a custom form (easy enough to do).  Or you could just call input box twice.